# Where are the E-Mail Templates?

Tags: craft3, emails

Am I completely stupid or have the e-mail settings been removed after an update?
I am searching for the text E-Mails they are sent if a new User is created, someone has his Passwort forgotten and so on… I am really sure that i saw this already but where?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: finally i found it… Under the Utilities… Not really logical would be better under the E-Mail settings

Answer (score 3):

These were moved to "Utilities" so they now have their own permission and users can have access to them without needing be have admin rights.